# tensorflow Unable to find a suitable algorithm for doing forward convolution

Tags: tensorflow

When running the PDE example on the [TensorFlow website](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/tutorials/pdes/index.html)

```
#Import libraries for simulation
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

def make_kernel(a):
  """Transform a 2D array into a convolution kernel"""
  a = np.asarray(a)
  a = a.reshape(list(a.shape) + [1,1])
  return tf.constant(a, dtype=1)

def simple_conv(x, k):
  """A simplified 2D convolution operation"""
  x = tf.expand_dims(tf.expand_dims(x, 0), -1)
  y = tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d(x, k, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
  return y[0, :, :, 0]

def laplace(x):
  """Compute the 2D laplacian of an array"""
  laplace_k = make_kernel([[0.5, 1.0, 0.5],
                           [1.0, -6., 1.0],
                           [0.5, 1.0, 0.5]])
  return simple_conv(x, laplace_k)



# Initial Conditions -- some rain drops hit a pond
N = 500

# Set everything to zero
u_init = np.zeros([N, N], dtype=np.float32)
ut_init = np.zeros([N, N], dtype=np.float32)

# Some rain drops hit a pond at random points
for n in range(40):
  a,b = np.random.randint(0, N, 2)
  u_init[a,b] = np.random.uniform()


# Parameters:
# eps -- time resolution
# damping -- wave damping
eps = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=())
damping = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=())

# Create variables for simulation state
U  = tf.Variable(u_init)
Ut = tf.Variable(ut_init)

# Discretized PDE update rules
U_ = U + eps * Ut
Ut_ = Ut + eps * (laplace(U) - damping * Ut)

# Operation to update the state
step = tf.group(
  U.assign(U_),
  Ut.assign(Ut_))

# Initialize state to initial conditions
tf.initialize_all_variables().run()

# Run 1000 steps of PDE
nsteps = 1000
for i in range(nsteps):
  # Step simulation
  step.run({eps: 0.03, damping: 0.04})
  # Visualize every 50 steps
  if i % 50 == 0:
    print("iter = %d, max(U) = %f, min(U) = %f" % \
        (i, np.max(U.eval()), np.min(U.eval())))

sess.close()
```

on  the GPU on my local machine, I get the following error in the loop at `step.run({eps: 0.03, damping: 0.04})`

> I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:755] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 750 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
>
> F tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:675] Check failed: status == CUDNN_STATUS_SUCCESS (3 vs. 0) Unable to find a suitable algorithm for doing forward convolution
>
> Aborted (core dumped)

When I run the code using the CPU `with tf.device('/cpu:0'):` it works fine. Also, I have run other examples using the GPU just fine.

Is this a feature they have yet to implement? Or did I make a mistake somewhere?

System information:

Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Graphics card: GeForce GTX 750 Ti

Installed version of CUDA and cuDNN: CUDA 7.5, cuNN v5

I installed the source by pulling from GitHub.  More information on the GitHub issue tracker: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2174

Comment: Please include a runnable example in the body of your question, not as a link. See [MCVE](/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

(1) TensorFlow Requirements(Please refer to the tensorflow manual)

The TensorFlow Python API supports Python 2.7 and Python 3.3+.

The GPU version (Linux only) works best with Cuda Toolkit 7.5 and cuDNN v4. other versions are supported (Cuda toolkit >= 7.0 and cuDNN 6.5(v2), 7.0(v3), v5) only when installing from sources.

(2) Make do

Therefore 
   (2-1)  remove cuDNN5 
   (2-2)  install cuDNN4 and setting

(2-3-1)  uninstall tensorflow
   (2-3-2)  install (gpu) tensorflow